# Kettle Pentaho - Getting records from two table which does not match on common Key (Merge)

Tags: kettle

I have two tables in transformation and I need to get data from two tables which does not meet on common key. i.e I am doing join on table A and B
from table A I need those records which are not present in table B. 
it will be helpful if someone can tell me what step I can use in Kettle spoon to do above transformation

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the Merge Join step. Under Join Type choose LEFT OUTER. After this step your results will look like this:

key_a|value_a|key_b|value_b

1 | 1| null | null

2    | 2     | null | null

3 | 3| 3| 3|

Then choose the Filter rows step and set key_b as the field and the condition to IS NULL.

If you also need records where key_a does not match key_b, choose the Join Type as FULL OUTER.

If both your tables are in a database of the same type, this can easily be achieved by using the Table input step and doing the join in the query itself:

```
SELECT table_a.key
, table_a.value
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON table_a.key = table_b.key
WHERE table_b.key IS NULL
```